# Event when window/stage lost focus

Tags: java, events, focus, javafx-2, stage

How can I run a piece of code (or more exactly: close the stage) when the JavaFX stage lost it's focus?

For example in Dropbox or Chrome: if you click the tray icon, a small window opens. If you click anywhere on the screen now, the window closes. Exactly this is the behaviour I want to create in my JavaFX application.

I searched a long time already for a solution, but couldn't find one...
So, I'm looking for something something like this:

```
stage.addEventHandler(EventType.FOCUS_LOST, new EventHandler() { /*...*/ } );
```

Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 25):

Add a listener to `stage.focusedProperty()`.

```
primaryStage.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
{
  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean onHidden, Boolean onShown)
  {
    <Your code here>
  }
});
```

Comment: just a note: `t` is an old value, `t1` is a new one. so, for this case `t` stands for `onHidden`, `t1` - `onShown`